# Biblatex and ACM Proceedings bibligraphy style

Tags: biblatex, acm

I would like to use biblatex in order to control for the amount of information which is outputed in the bibliography (e.g., doi, issn, urls) but the problem is that the original [ACM Proceedings format](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sigproc-sp.pdf) produces abbrevated names while the default numeric format produces the full names in the bibliography. I'm not sure how to do this and I'm overwhelmed by the amount of customization that is possible to do.

Original version:

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@book{book_2014,
  title = {Book Title},
  publisher = {{Publisher} Name},
  author = {Doe, John and Bar, Foo. and Jane Doe},
  month = april,
  year = {2014}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish,english,american]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}

\lipsum{1}~\citep{book_2014}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{example}

\end{document}
```

[image: original BibTeX version]

Biblatex version

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{filecontents}{paper.bib}
@book{book_2014,
  title = {Book Title},
  publisher = {{Publisher} Name},
  author = {Doe, John and Bar, Foo. and Jane Doe},
  month = april,
  year = {2014}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish,english,american]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[firstinits=false,
            uniquename=false,
            uniquelist=false,
            hyperref=auto,
            maxbibnames=99,
            maxcitenames=2,
            style=numeric,
            citestyle=numeric,
            backref=false,
            natbib=true,
            backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{}

\AtEveryBibitem{
 \clearlist{address}
 \clearfield{date}
 \clearfield{eprint}
 \clearfield{doi}
 \clearfield{isbn}
 \clearfield{issn}
 \clearlist{location}
 \clearfield{month}
 \clearfield{labelmonth}
 \clearfield{series}

 \ifentrytype{book}{
   \clearfield{url}
 }{
   \ifentrytype{misc}{
   }{
    \clearfield{url}
    \clearlist{publisher}
     \clearname{editor}
   }
 }
}

\bibliography{paper}

\begin{document}

\lipsum{1}~\citep{book_2014}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Biblatex version]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. It is great that you provide some code and you can make it much more useful by completing it to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I've found a solution, it is the `style=trad-abbrv` in the biblatex `usepackage` statement

Comment: `firstinits=true` is the secret option you are looking for (oddly enough though you explicitly set `firstinits=false`, why?). There is no point in setting `citestyle` to `numeric`, if `style` is already `numeric`. `hyperref=auto` is already the default setting, so no need to repeat it in the preamble. Furthermore you might want to think about switching to [Biber](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biber) (`backend=biber`) instead of BibTeX (the `uniquename` and `uniquelist` features are only available with Biber, they are all set to `false` by default as well, so no need to mention them either).

Comment: Another note: If you want to suppress the output of the `urldate`, `\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{}` is not a good idea (I'm not really sure whether it has any effect at all). Furthermore, the `\bibliography` command is deprecated in favour of `\addbibresource`, so write `\addbibresource{paper.bib}` (note the file extension, has to be included here) instead of `\bibliography{paper}`. To suppress `doi`, `isbn` etc. it is generally preferred to use `doi=false`, `isbn=false` as a load-time option (this will only work for some fields though, consult the manual for further information about that).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments, I've switched to Biber, previously I had some problems with it, but now everyting works so I'm going to use it form now :) Some of the staff that is there is left from thee other paper I was writing that used author-year format so I was setting all those things things that do not make much sense for this case

Comment: You might like to write the answer to this question yourself, so it does not hang around unsolved here even though you found an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to do that, When I wanted to do that I was not able as I didn't have priviledge

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution. The style which is used by the ACM Proceedings format can be specified using `style=trad-abbrv` in the usepackage statement.

Comment: You might also want to mention the `firstinits=true` option.